# Getting iGPU to Work on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, steam, amd-graphics, 16.10

Okay I will quick summarize everything that happened in the past 24 hours.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 2 days ago. Tried to game, couldnt play anything with Ubuntu and Steam forcing Intel HD 3000 GPU. I hop onto Discord (/r/linux_gaming and /r/pcmasterrace) and Linux_Gaming helps me get my GPU working but I get this in game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciFsP2Z-vMI

I updated my Kernel and I had more issues so I formatted and installed 16.10. When I ran `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'` I got `Kernel driver in use: i915` `Kernel driver in use: radeon`

I had issues setting up Steam cause it was trying to boot/install itself under Intel GPU (I used Steam's deb at that time). I removed the deb installation. Installed via Terminal. It opened and I reinstalled Rocket League via my Backup.

In game I got 30 fps in Menu (VS 60 in W10) and I didnt have any issues except audio from the video I shared. It worked quite well if you dont count FPS drops and the sound bug.

Now the actual question is how do I get my AMD HD 6470M to work so I can play games? This is what I have in additional drivers:
[image]

I can provide other info if needed but PLEASE help me get this fixed. I have tried countless stuff and asked the same question in several subreddits and here but didnt get any help.

Please; even the tiny amount of help is appreciated! So please help!